# MTLCopyAllDevices return noting

Tags: macos, gpu, metal

I want to list all the gpu devices in mac with the following codes

```
NSArray *devices = MTLCopyAllDevices();
for (id device in devices) {
    NSLog(@"device: %@", [device name]);
}
NSLog(@"get devices");
```

Nothing was returned. However, there was actually a GPU device, which can be got by typing the following command in osx terminal:

```
/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType
```

The output of the above command is:

```
Display:

  Type: GPU
  Bus: PCI
  VRAM (Total): 3 MB
  Device ID: 0x0405
  Revision ID: 0x0000
  Kernel Extension Info: No Kext Loaded
  Displays:
    Display:
      Resolution: 1024 x 768
      Pixel Depth: 32-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
      Main Display: Yes
      Mirror: Off
      Online: Yes
      Display Asleep: Yes
  Vendor ID: 0x15ad
```

Could anyone point out what's problem ? Thanks.

Comment: Does the Mac you're running this on support Metal? List can be found here https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT205073

Comment: It was a virtual machine.The codes containing metal functions could be complied and linked successfully, does it mean Metal is supported?

Comment: If `MTLCopyAllDevices` returns an empty array, Metal is not supported. I wouldn't expect this to work on a VMware virtual machine.

Comment: It was a little strange. I have tried two virtual machines,  one with desktop, the GPU of which could be displayed correctly, and the other without desktop, the GPU of which could not be displayed correctly.

Comment: Interesting. What does `system_profiler` say about the GPU that worked?

Comment: @warrenm, I made a mistake. The one that worked was a romate host, instead of a virtual one.